# Remove nodes in Gephi

Tags: nodes, gephi

I have a graph in Gephi, and I need to remove nodes that have fewer than 10 neighbors, or in other words - to leave in the graph the nodes that have more than 10 neighbors.

I thought about some filter, but I don't find which filter can give me this request...

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps shown in the screenshot below. The steps are

1. Go to **Filters>Range>Degree**, select **Degree** and *double click*,
2. Under **Filter parameters**, you will see **Range**.
3. Bottom right of Gephi, you see a slider, where you can adjust the *degree range you want to keep*. In your case the range values larger than or equal to 10,
4. Click **Filter** and that's it.

[image]